# how to compute the risk free rate for a given maturity of an option contract?

Tags: options, interest-rates

i'm working on options with different maturities. I need to correspond a risk free rate for each maturity. What rate should i consider as risk free rate?
thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The risk free rate is used to get the present value of future payoff, so you should use the rate of a risk-free instrument (e.g. a Treasury note) that has roughly the same maturity of the option you are valuing.

If you option expires in a time that does not have an exact Treasury instrument, you can get a rough approximation by interpolating between two published rates.  There are more sophisticated methods, but for option valuation the interest rate is generally a small factor, other than for long-dated deep in-the-money options.

Comment: thanks. so since i'm working on options written on the SP500, is it correct to consider us treasury bills with maturities of 1 month, 3 months and 6 months?

Comment: If you have options that expire in 1, 3, and 6 months then yes, those are perfect risk-free rates to use.